# Synfusion : Image from url not showing in html to pdf conversion

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to generate pdf from html which is working fine but the issue I am having is that my images are not showing: the images are from a url `<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/large-beautiful-drops-transparent-rain-260nw-668593321.jpg" />` I think the images have not been loaded before the conversion. Please how can I delay the conversion or achieve this i.e ensure the image is rendered with the pdf.

````
            WebKitConverterSettings settings = new WebKitConverterSettings();

            var baseUrl = url;
            settings.PdfHeader = HeaderHTMLtoPDF(url");
            settings.PdfFooter = FooterHTMLtoPDF({url});

            //Set WebKit path
            var contentRoot = _configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
            settings.WebKitPath = Path.Combine(contentRoot, "QtBinariesWindows");
            settings.Margin.Top = 30;
            //Assign WebKit settings to HTML converter
            htmlConverter.ConverterSettings = settings;


            var pdfViewUrl = $"{baseUrl}/api/pdf";
            Task<PdfDocument> convertPdfTask = Task<PdfDocument>.Factory.StartNew(() => htmlConverter.Convert(pdfViewUrl));
            PdfDocument document = convertPdfTask.Result;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            document.Save(stream);
            document.Close(true);```
````

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to convert your image to base64 so the image is inline in the html.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the conversion with provided details, its working properly. We have creates a simple html with provided image and it is properly converted to PDF document.

The reported image missing issue may occurs due to missing of OPENSSL assemblies. To access the resource from HTTPS site, the HTML converter requires OPENSSL assemblies. So, please make sure the OPENSSL assemblies are available in the machine where the conversion takes place. Please refer below links for more details,

**Prerequisites** - https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#openssl

**Troubleshooting** - https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/converting-html-to-pdf#troubleshooting

However, the below mentioned OPENSSL assemblies can be placed in the Windows system folder of the machine. (for 64-bit machine, it should be place in $SystemDrive\Windows\SysWOW64 and for 32-bit machine, it should be place in $SystemDrive\Windows\System32).

- libeay32.dll
- libssl32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

**Note** : I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: "it should be place in $SystemDrive\Windows\System32" are you serious? This is unbelievable. That is a show blocker for me.